# Save image to custom folder android on onPictureTaken

Tags: android, camera

i need to save an image to a custom folder in my phone.
my code is

```
@Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data != null) {
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 0000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fName = "Image" + n + ".jpg";
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(fName)); 
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera.startPreview();
}
```

**not working**

Comment: is there a exception or is the image not appearing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (data != null) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);

    if(bitmap!=null){

                        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirr");
                        if(!file.isDirectory()){
                            file.mkdir();
                        }

                        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirr",System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");


                        try 
                        {
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fileOutputStream);

                            fileOutputStream.flush();
                            fileOutputStream.close();
                        }
                        catch(IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch(Exception exception)
                        {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
    }
}


Dont forget to add permission:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find ans from below code

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
if (data != null) {
Bitmap m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +    "Image.jpg";
if (m_bitmap != null || destinationPath != null)
{
FileOutputStream m_out = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);
m_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, m_out);
}
}
```

Hope this code helps you

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create the destination folder you want to save the file into. So, in your Android sdk folder, you create the MediaFiles folder. In this folder you can then create your file.

Here's some code you can try.

```
@Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data != null) {
               FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 0000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fName = "Image" + n + ".jpg";
                    outStream = new   FileOutputStream(GetPathForFileName(fName)); 
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera.startPreview();
}

private String GetPathForFileName(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            String savePath = GetSaveFolderFromConfiguration();

            File file = new File(savePath + "/" + fileName);

            return savePath + "/" + fileName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionForm.ShowException(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

public static String GetSaveFolderFromConfiguration() throws Exception
    {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MediaFiles";
        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.exists())
            return path;
        else
            f.mkdir();
        return path;
    }
```